# MPAndroidChart how to make y-axis to start at non-zero value?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library and have a set of data entries where the Y values are between 20 - 30 and I'm currently displaying it in a Line chart. However, I notice that there is a big gap because the Y-axis starts at 0 instead of 20.

[image: Screenshot]

How can I make Y-axis to start at the 20 instead of 0? Or even better the minimum of all y-values?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Please add a MCVE to the question, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find this in the [documentation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/YAxis-(YLabels)).

`yAxis.setAxisMinValue(...)`

allows you to adjust the lower limit of the axis to your needs.

Comment: Apparently I was using version 2.2.2. The problem is gone after I update to version 2.2.3. How, setAxisMinValue is still the right method to call. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The last version includes a left and right axis. You can set to zero like this (Kotlin):

```
chart.axisLeft.axisMinimum = 0f
chart.axisRight.axisMinimum = 0f
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set zero in Bar Graph like this in Java

```
 barChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinValue(0f);
 barChart.getAxisRight().setAxisMinValue(0f);
```